# Blogger Conditional Tag

Tags: html, if-statement, conditional-statements, blogger

Whats wrong with this Blogger conditional tag? The aim is to show the widget 'HTML6' only on the those posts which come under the label 'News' and not on other posts.

```
 <b:includable id='main'>     
 <b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "News")'>
 <style>#HTML6 { display: block; }</style>
 <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
 <h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
 </b:if>     
 <b:else/>
 <style>#HTML6 { display: none; }</style>
 </b:if>
 </b:includable>
```

Got this from a discussion on blogger help forum, but unfortunately, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

`data:post.labels` works only inside Blog widget, you can do the following

```
<b:widget id='Blog1' type='Blog'>

   <b:includable id='main'>
     <b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "News")'>
       <style>#HTML6 { display: block; }</style>    
     <b:else/>
       <style>#HTML6 { display: none; }</style>
     </b:if>
   </b:includable>

 </b:widget>
```

Comment: Tried that, too. But in that case the widget shows the title and content of the main blog only!

Comment: Please provide the rest of the code. The lines just above and below it. Maybe it can be wrapped up in other conditional tags.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the div tag, try this:

```html
<div class='widget HTML' data-version='1' id='HTML6'>
<b:includable id='main'>     
 <b:if cond='data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "News")'>
 <style>#HTML6 { display: block; }</style>
 <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
 <h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
 </b:if>     
 <b:else/>
 <style>#HTML6 { display: none; }</style>
 </b:if>
 </b:includable>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for that:

```
<b:if cond='data:view.search.label == &quot;Label-name&quot;' name='Label-name'>
 <!--But the style code here-->
  </b:if>
```